# How to Define Variables in the SQL and Use it as a Column in other Query?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a list of **products**, each product has different types of discounts, I need to query during products to get products that have specific prices (after calculating all discounts). I chose the below code to be written:

```
 $products = Product::query()
        ->select('*')
        ->selectRaw('IF(
            (base_discount_start_time IS NULL OR base_discount_start_time <= NOW()) AND (base_discount_end_time IS NULL OR base_discount_end_time >= NOW()),
            IF(base_discount_type = "percent", (customer_price - (customer_price * (base_discount / 100))), (customer_price - base_discount)),
            customer_price
            ) AS price, IF(
            (marketing_discount_start_time IS NULL OR marketing_discount_start_time <= NOW()) AND (marketing_discount_end_time IS NULL OR marketing_discount_end_time >= NOW()),
            IF(marketing_discount_type = "percent", (price - (price * (marketing_discount / 100))), (price - marketing_discount)),
             price
            ) AS site_price')
        ->having('site_price', '>', 300);
```

But there's a problem I can't use the define price variable in the next SQL query and I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'price' in 'field list'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referencing your first `price` calculation, you can use `(SELECT price)`:

```php
$products = Product::query()
        ->select('*')
        ->selectRaw('
            IF(
                (base_discount_start_time IS NULL OR base_discount_start_time <= NOW()) AND (base_discount_end_time IS NULL OR base_discount_end_time >= NOW()),
                IF(base_discount_type = "percent", (customer_price - (customer_price * (base_discount / 100))), (customer_price - base_discount)),
                customer_price
            ) AS price,
            IF(
                (marketing_discount_start_time IS NULL OR marketing_discount_start_time <= NOW()) AND (marketing_discount_end_time IS NULL OR marketing_discount_end_time >= NOW()),
                IF(marketing_discount_type = "percent", ((SELECT price) - ((SELECT price) * (marketing_discount / 100))), ((SELECT price) - marketing_discount)),
                (SELECT price)
            ) AS site_price')
        ->having('site_price', '>', 300);
```